# Probability of getting atleast 4 head when a coin is tossed 7 times.

Tags: probability

What is the probability of getting atleast 4 head when a coin is tosses 7 times?

I know that probability of getting atleast 4 head includes P(4) + P(5) + P(6) + P(7).

Since the order of the outcomes doesn't matter, therefore the total number of outcomes are 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 = 14.

Now,

```
probability of getting exactly 4 = 1/14
Probability of getting exactly 5 = 1/14
probability of getting exactly 6 = 1/14
probability of getting exactly 7 = 1/14
```

So the probability of getting atleast 4 is 1/14 + 1/14 + 1/14 + 1/14 = 4/14 or 2/7.

Is it wrong?

Comment: Notice that your method would imply that the probability of getting at least zero heads is $8/14$, which is not $1$. So yes, there are some mistakes in your work.

Comment: @JoseAvilez so I think the probability of getting exactly 5 is 1/13 and probability of 6 is 1/12 and probability of 7 is 1/11. Is it right?

Comment: No. Please see this: [Binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).

Comment: "Since the order of outcomes does not matter"...Note that $HHHHTTT$ and $HTHHHTT$ are different outcomes. There are a total of $2^7$ outcomes, not $14$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can answer this question using symmetry.  Because the coins are fair, the probability of a heads or a tails on any flip is equal, so the probability of getting at least $4$ heads is necessarily the same as the probability of getting at least $4$ tails, which is the same as the probability of getting $3$ or fewer heads.  But since these two possibilities ($4$ or more heads vs. $3$ or fewer heads) are mutually exclusive and exhaust the entire sample space and they have equal probability, the probability of getting at least $4$ heads has to be $0.5$.

Your analysis is incorrect for the reasons stated in the comments -- essentially, there are many more combinations that result in $4$ heads than result in $7$ heads, so those two results don't have equal probabilities for the same reason that rolling a $7$ on a pair of dice is much more likely than rolling a $12$.  Think of it this way:  If you flip the coins one at a time and the first one comes up tails, you have no chance at all to finish with $7$ heads, but you're still in the running to finish with $4$ heads.

Comment: The probability of exactly $k$ heads out of $7$ flips is $\frac{\binom 7k}{2^7}$.

Comment: @Anonymous Re the above comment note that by the [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem), $$2^7 = (1 + 1)^7 = \sum_{k=0}^7 \binom{7}{k}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Think of it as first simply counting the number of ways we can pick $4$ coins to be heads of the $7$. This can be done in $\binom{7}{4}$. Similarly because this is $at$ $least$ $4$, we also consider the case with $5$ heads, so $\binom{7}{5}$. Then $\binom{7}{6}$ and finally when all $7$ are heads; $\binom{7}{7}$. Summing all the cases and dividing by $2^7$ gives us $1/2$.

(A faster way of finding this sum if it was in a competition setting would be to notice that $\binom{7}{4}=\binom{7}{3}$, and so we can abuse the result that $\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}=2^n$ and obtain our sum is $2^7/2=2^6$). Then the probability is $\frac{2^6}{2^7}=\frac{1}{2}$).

EDIT: Nevermind.